# Find and replace all occurrences of a string inside an HTML tag in one pass

Tags: html, regex, replace, notepad++

I need a regular expression to search for and replace multiple occurrences of a text string within a delimited section of text.

Let's say there is HTML code with one or more spans that have a certain class. Each span may have none, one or multiple occurrences of the string `{abc}` inside, e.g.

```
<p>lorem ipsum dolor <span class="xyz">sid amet{abc}et pluribus {abc} unum{abc} diex 
et mon droit</span> you'll never walk alone</p>
```

Thus I need a regex pair to replace all occurrences of `{abc}` within `<span id="xyz">` with `{def}` *in a single pass*.

This is for use in a text editor such as *Notepad++ and the like* and needs to be be a *PCRE/UNIX-style* regular expression.

What I have is,

find: `(<span class="xyz">)([^<]*)\{abc\}([^<]*<)`

replace: `\1\2{def}\3`

This *does work* for one occurrence within a span, but in case of more occurrences, I have to run replacement multiple times, in cycle, while I need that to be *one-pass*.

I wonder how can I achieve that. I suppose this is a pretty common case, somehow I could not find similar things concerning the need to be one-pass, no cycles, no code, and I'd like to get an idea how this could be done in principle.

Comment: So, Notepad++ or which editor? Notepad++ uses PCRE in Search and Replace, SublimeText uses Boost, TextMate uses Oniguruma. Well, all these have a `\G` operator support, but the first two also support a useful `\K` operator.

Comment: You can make use of `\G` in Notepad++, like `(?:<span class="xyz">|\G(?!^))(?:[^<{]*|\{(?!abc))\K\{abc\}`. This is not properly tested and will fail on nested tags. Also it's usually a bad idea to handle html in regex.

Comment: I'd try something like `(<span class="xyz">|\G(?!^))((?:[^<{]|\{(?!abc\}))*)\{abc\}` and replace with `$1$2{def}` to avoid using `\K` that is not that widely present. This is not a Unix regex though.

Comment: So, it is for UltraEdit? There should be a combo with the regex flavor, and there must be an option called `Perl` - that is for PCRE regex. Then you can use `(?:<span class="xyz">|(?!^)\G)(?:[^<{]|\{(?!abc\}))*\K\{abc\}` and replace with `{def}`.

Comment: The best regex I can think of something like `(?:<span class="xyz">|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!</?span\b|\{abc\}).)*\K\{abc\}` to replace with `{def}` for a PCRE regex engine. It won't work for nested `<span>` tags, but will support any other tags inside `<span>`.

Comment: **Wiktor Stribiżew**, **Sebastian Proske**: Yes, Notepad++ and PCRE work perfect for me. Thank you, all your suggestions worked like charm, I got a good insight.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in Notepad++

Find what : `(?:<span class="xyz">|\G)[^<]*?\K\{abc\}(?=[^<]*<\/span>)`

Replace with : `{def}`

Search mode : Regular expression

Note that because of the `[^<]*` there is an assumption that there are no other tags within the span tag.